# Error creating bean with name : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    @Autowired
    AccountDAO accountDao;
    
    
    //since we have added support for transaction manager
    //@Transactional is use to automatically begin and end transaction
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean saveAccount(Account account) {
        return accountDao.saveAccount(account);
        //return false;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return accountDao.saveAccount(account);
    }
```

**DAO**

```
@Repository
public class AccountDAOImpl implements AccountDAO {
    
    //we r @Autowiring sessionFactory cuz hibernate use sessionFactory for db connectivity
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public boolean saveAccount(Account account) {
        boolean saveFlag = true;
        
        AccountEntity accountEntity = new AccountEntity();
        accountEntity.setAccountNo(account.getAccountNo());
        accountEntity.setAccountHolderName(account.getAccountHolderName());
        accountEntity.setAccountType(account.getAccountType());
        accountEntity.setAccountBalance(account.getAccountBalance());
        accountEntity.setDateOfBirth(account.getDateOfBirth());
        accountEntity.setPsCode(account.getPsCode());
        
        try {
            Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            currentSession.save(accountEntity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            saveFlag = false;
        }
        
        return saveFlag;
    }
```

**.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/psbankdb?useSSL=false" />
        <property name="user" value="psbankdb" />
        <property name="password" value="123" />
    </bean>
    
    <!-- sessionFactory is used to connect with db using above dataSource(ref="dataSource)" -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" ref="com.ps.springmvc.psbankApp" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <!-- to display sql property on the console while execution -->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- TransactionManager it uses session factory as ref -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- it allow us to use annotation to eliminate manual coding to start and stop transaction -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />
```

**getting below error**

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'accountService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'accountDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/bankAppContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.ps.springmvc.psbankApp' while setting bean property 'packagesToScan'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'com.ps.springmvc.psbankApp' available
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)

Comment: what is com.ps.springmvc.psbankApp?

Comment: package containing controller, services, model, DAO etc

Comment: You are using `<property name="packagesToScan" ref="com.ps.springmvc.psbankApp" />
` and I highly doubt you have a bean named `com.ps.springmvc.psbankApp` of type `String` in your context. Change `ref` to `value`.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this error because spring boot cannot find `AccountService` bean on startup.

The [spring-docs][of] NoSuchBeanDefinitionException explains

> Exception thrown when a BeanFactory is asked for a bean instance for
> which it cannot find a definition. This may point to a non-existing
> bean, a non-unique bean, or a manually registered singleton instance
> without an associated bean definition.

So IN short the bean wasn't registered in your case.
You can follow one of the methods below to register the beans and solve this problem.

1. Declare a `@Bean` method in a `@Configuration` class or add tag `<bean>` in XML
   configuration.
2. `@Component` or `@Service` can be registered into spring bean-factory via
   through `@ComponentScan` or `<context:component-scan ... />` in XML configuration

Comment: The problem is the usage of a `ref` instead of a `value`. I suggest reading the stacktrace, before constructing an answer.